# VB.NET Error when debugging when "Release" selected

Tags: vb.net

Just wanna ask if why my vb.net application is getting errors when I'm debugging it with the "Release" selected. It always says "Type 'MySqlBackup' is not defined.

Comment: We need more information. Is `MySqlBackup` a class in your application?

Comment: have you declared any variable named `MySqlBackup` or is it your class name?

Comment: turn on option strict(  option strict on)

Comment: Technically, you aren't debugging when running as 'release.'  What is the project configuration like?  Are all your projects building to the same release/debug version?  Having mismatched build configurations can cause one project not to be able to find the updates you made to another project

Comment: i declared it as private, "Private mb As New MySqlBackup